# Remote Desktop pauses execution when unfocused

Tags: winforms, remote-desktop

I've a virtual machine which I'm accessing via Remote Desktop Connection (RDC). I'm running an EXE which is firing a number of windows within a loop and closes them down after. All works fine while I'm physically looking after the process. Once an RDC window stops to be the topmost one (say I swithc  to MS Outlook) - the whole process gets paused until my RDC window gets 'focused' again. I wonder how do I keep things working independetnly of RDC window focus state?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you positive it's tied to the RDC client, e.g. that behavior doesn't happen if you connect through, say, VMRC or the Hyper-V Viewer?

Comment: Hard to say, I only have RDC on my machine. The way I know that it's doing nothing when unfcoused is the DB - the app logs calls every 15 seconds, which it's doing perfectly fine while focused. Once RDC window is sent back - no DB entries get created.

Comment: Could it be that your loop is somehow tied to the application's message dispatch loop? If that's the case, it would only run if there are messages to pump, and an inactive RDC window might not send any input message whatsoever to the remote end, thus blocking your loop.

Comment: A good point. It's a robot I'm working on (it's doing something with an legacy app using Win API). I've to use STA beacuse of Clipboard - could that be a problem?

Comment: How do you trigger a loop iteration? Are you using a timer or are you relying only on `GetMessage()`? Seeing some code would help a lot :)

Comment: I'm using a timer only. ode has nothing it just execute a routine on timer. I'm using WinAPID a lot - PostMessage in particular. It looks like the thred gets paused once RDC window becomes inactive and resumes it once it gains focus...